# C++, linux, how to pop_back() efficiently a non latin1 char from a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a problem with `string` manipulation, first consider these `string`s :

```
string s1 = "Graveworm";
string s2 = "Motörhead"; //the best of the best, just to say...
```

as you can see, each of them have 9 `char`s, yes.. but no... because when I `pop_back()` a letter with accent like "é" I have to `pop_back()` two `char`s.

so now, there is a way to know how many `char`(s) I have to `pop_back()`, remember that `s1` and `s2` are written in the code.

note :: while writing this question, a possible method come in my mind : get the size of the string and delete char by char as long as the size hasn't decrease of one;
well, I tried this :

```
if(s->size()>0){
         int size = s->size();
         for(i=size; i > size-1 ;i--){
           s->pop_back();
         }
```

not working as expected

Comment: Why do you have to delete symbol twice? I suppose you don't use Unicode?

Comment: not sure why, but I guess it's because xlib is old

Comment: This depends on the encoding of the text in the string -- what encoding are you using? UTF-8?

Comment: _"as you can see, each of them have 9 chars, yes"_ No, you should check what `strlen("Motörhead")` returns. Similarly for `s2.length()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Linux distros use the [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding for non-ASCII characters.  UTF-8 has the property that all non-initial bytes have a bit pattern of `10xxxxxx`, so one way you can pop an entire UTF-8 character would be like so:

```
// Note: How this gets compiled depends on your compiler's input character set.
// For GCC, see the -finput-charset and -fexec-charset compiler options.
std::string s = "Motörhead";

while (s.size() > 0)
{
    char c = s.back();
    s.pop_back();

    // If we found an initial character, we're done
    if ((c & 0xC0) != 0x80)
        break;
}
```

This works by popping characters until we find an initial character (one with an initial bit pattern of `0xxxxxxx` or `11xxxxxx`).  It also has a safety net to bail out and avoid Undefined Behavior if somehow the string you have is malformed and isn't actually valid UTF-8.

Keep in mind, though, that this code makes assumptions about its target environment.  If you run this in any non-UTF-8 environments, you'll need to make sure that your strings are converted to UTF-8 before using this code and that they're converted back into the target environment's encoding before being output (e.g. printed to the console).  If you fail to do so, it will fail in surprising ways (frequently with some type of [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)).

Comment: +1, though I wouldn't use `std::wstring` if possible, since it has all the same problems as `std::string` with ASCII but merely hides some of them under the carpet by using wider characters (either way you end up needing the notion of an "encoding" which can represent characters across multiple elements of the string).

Comment: Utf-32 would like a word with you: utf-16 does not let you avoid this issue.  There are multi-`wchar_t` characters too.

Comment: Good points about UTF-16, I've removed the note about `std::wstring`.

Comment: What has UTF-16 got to do with anything?  `wstring` might hold UTF-16 characters on Windows, but that's not portable, and `sizeof(wchar_t)==4` on many other platforms.

Comment: your answer is very good, could you explain to me what's `(c & 0xC0)`does plz ? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @bob: That's the [*bitwise AND operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).  It checks if the top two bits of the character `c` are different from `10` by masking out the lower 6-bits with the hexadecimal bitmask `0xC0` (which is `11000000` in binary).

Answer (score 3):

On modern Linux in particular most (all?) text and code editors save `"Motörhead"` in the file with 10 bytes between the quotation marks. Try `hexdump` on your *source code* file and you'll see something like

```
00000050  32 20 3d 20 22 4d 6f 74  c3 b6 72 68 65 61 64 22  |2 = "Mot..rhead"|
```

You can achieve this behavior in a portable manner with C++11 if you use `u8"Motörhead"`

As for finding out how many bytes are in each multibyte character, it's rarely necessary, but if you really need it, [std::mblen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mblen), [std::mbrlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrlen) and related functions can help.

Answer (score 2):

If your encoding is UTF-8, you can take advantage of the coding to know when you've reached the first byte of a codepoint. That will be when the byte value is `< 128` (the ASCII range) or when it's between `0xc0` and `0xff`.

Unfortunately this only tells you when you've popped a codepoint. An actual character may consist of several codepoints if you're considering combining characters.